# How to correctly view pdf in browser using DotVVM?

Tags: c#, pdf, dotvvm

I'm trying to view PDF in a browser tab using DotVVM.

I've tried to use `ReturnFile()` method described here https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/tutorials/advanced-returning-files/1-1

with `additionalHeaders` but it haven't worked.

```
var additionalHeaders = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Disposition", "inline")
};
using (var file = ...)
{
    Context.ReturnFile(file.Stream, ItemId + "-" + type + ".pdf", "application/pdf", additionalHeaders);
}
```

Is there any way to view PDF in a browser using `ReturnFile()` Method or do I have to create my own `DotvvMPresenter`? Or is there any other suitable way how to manage that?

I've also tried to set up `Context.HttpContext.Response.Body/Headers/ContentType`
, but even that haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DotVVM 2.3.0, we have added an overload of`ReturnFile` which allows to specify `Content-Disposition` header. If you set it to `inline`, it should display the document instead of downloading it.